# Authentication Required pop-up appearing endlessly- tomcat 8

Tags: xml, tomcat

I'm using tomcat 8.5.13 for deploying my first webapp on AWS instance with redhat. Tomcat has been installed successfully as I can see the tomcat landing page. Now there are 2 parts of the problem ;

1. when I try to access 'Manager App' it throws 'authentication required' pop-up
   repeatedly even after providing username and pwd details. It keeps on 
   appearing endlessly until I close it forcefully but then the error 401 
   appears.

   I had updated Tomacat-users.xml as below;

   ```
   <tomcat-users>
     <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
     <role rolename="manager-status"/>
     <role rolename="manager-script"/>
     <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
     <user username="******" password="******" roles="manager-gui,manager-
     status,manager-script,manager-jmx"/>**

   </tomcat-users>
   ```
2. Second part of the problem is that if I remove the first line i.e.

   ```
   <tomcat-users>
   ```

   it accepts the username and password and allows me access to 'Tomcat 
   Web Application Manager' page. However, attempt to open the webapp itself 
   fails with the error message given below;

   **HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
   Type Status Report
   Message /DevopsBank-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/
   Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.**

Can you please advise what is going wrong.

Comment: I see second part of the problem has something amiss. Please read it as -  Second part of the problem is that if I remove the first line i.e.        
  <tomcat-users>                                                                                               it accepts the username...............................................

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of commenting your question, you should edit and improve it so others can help you more easily.

Comment: @Pharaoh - thanks, updated question.

Comment: are you using tomcat 8.5.13 in your local machine to deploy the app to AWS

Answer (score 0):

The tomcat-users.xml needs the XML namespaces mentioned. Make sure you have them in place like below:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
```

Comment: Request you to try the below:    
1. Make sure any other instance of tomcat not running                                                                   
2. The password of your created user does not contain '<' or '>' characters 
3. kill java processes, clean tomcat work directory and restart

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use local tomcat installation. AWS is cloud computing PaaS service . So they have tomcat already installed . Try following this docs by amazon to deploy your app

[Creating and Deploying Java Applications on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html)

Comment: May I know why you think so? Tomcat is installed on AWS instance.

Comment: Thats what Platform as service is all about in cloud computing

Answer (score 0):

Below config works fine for me

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">

  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="123" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="123" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="123" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="souvik" password="xyz123" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status" />
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Yes, it is working as I was  able to login as Manager. However, while trying to launch the webapp it is throwing 404, as mentioned in the part 2 of the question.